# How to use comma separator to display my double value as currency value in WinRT?

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

i want to use comma separator to display my double value as currency value in WinRT XAML?

like

`<TextBlock Text="{Binding Amount, StringFormat={}{0:C}}" />`

I need to achieve this in XAML, not in C# using IValueConverter.

Thanks in advance.

Joy Rex

Comment: It doesn't currently exist. Your only option is to use a ValueConverter.

Comment: is it a bug? can we expect this in future? @WiredPrairie

Comment: it's not a bug. WinRT came from Silverlight, which also did not have it. I can't say whether it's coming in the future. The converter is about 8 lines of code though ... so I'd just suggest that. There are many people who've written something compatible already if you do a search.

Comment: By saying you need to achieve it in XAML and not with `IValueConverter` you are trying to answer your question yourself while also possibly limiting yourself from getting a valid answer if that isn't currently doable with just XAML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to note on this thread, the [Windows.Globalization.NumberFormatting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.globalization.numberformatting.aspx) APIs are available for both currency and decimal formatting, and automatically applies the user's locale-specific or customized number formats along with currency symbol placement. The [Number formatting and parsing sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Number-formatting-and-bb10ba3d) shows all the variations.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like something that should be delegated to be handled by the platform, not by some arbitrary format string, doesn't it? I believe this should happen automatically for users using a locale that uses commas as separators such as Polish. I don't have much recent experience with that in .NET, but perhaps a decimal type would make it work if double doesn't. Also remember that you can simply expose an `AmountAsString` property that is formatted by your view model since you only bind it one-way into a `TextBlock` anyway. Oh and otherwise - there is nothing wrong with an `IValueConverter`.

Comment: @Filip_Shakun, I have achieved my requirement by 'IValueConverter' in my application, but i have posted my query here to know that is there other possibilities to achieve my requirement through 'XAML' ? as these support is available in the WPF/SL also.

Comment: It is not available in WinRT/XAML as you have already noticed. Of course you might think it was exposed differently, but I don't believe it was unless you'd consider the [`Language`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.frameworkelement.language(v=win.10).aspx) property as the way to control decimal separators. It's so easy to implement a generic converter though that I don't think it is a big problem.